# Looking for a method in flash to read a string from a local app

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am looking for a way that can be used in my flash app to read a string from my local application, currently I am using activex to communication with the app and then pass that to flash. But I am wondering is there any alternatives that use pure flash techniques.

Comment: Is this using ActionScript 2 or 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LocalConnection in ActionScript 3 to invoke a method in another LocalConnection object. The communication can be:

```
* Within a single SWF file
* Between multiple SWF files
* Between content (SWF-based or HTML-based) in AIR applications
* Between content (SWF-based or HTML-based) in an AIR application and SWF content running in a browser
```

The following link gives examples and documentation:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html

Comment: The local application is a WIN32 application running as a background service, is it doable?

Comment: This is for communicating with other Flash apps. However, you can use the Flash OCX to pass parameters to flash within your Win32 app.